# Make a rule that allows only those who are online from the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm new to firebase and rules in firebase.
I want to do something like this:
I have firestore users, and each user has a boolean field isOnline, for example in the image I added:

[image]

I have a collection of users, inside I have the names of the users, and inside I have a field of isOnline.
Here in the picture, frontend4 user isOnline's field is true, so for him I will agree to use the site.

This is the rules I'm trying to do, I want to access my user's isOnline, and check if it's isOnline, and if so, then give it access.

The rules I made do not work, I do not quite understand why.

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
      match /users/{itemId}{
        allow read, write: if itemId.isOnline = true; 
      }
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you try `allow read, write: if itemId.isOnline == true; ` ?

Comment: I tried to do it now, but it does not work, I get an error `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: This should work `allow read, write: if resource.data.isOnline == true;`

Comment: Rules on their own do nothing. Can you edit your question to also show the minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the comment, I did not understand what you mean, can you explain more what code you mean?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My problem is this, I add a user through a server side in Nodejs, but I also use listners in react, and I want to give only the user access to the listener and not give access to everyone. I've been really desperate about it, for 3 weeks now I'm trying to fix it and do not know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Validation as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    // Allow the user to read data if the document has the 'isOnline' to true
    match /users/{itemId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.isOnline == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code you wrote does not solve my problem, I still get the same error. what can we do?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show: 1) the updated rules, 2) the minimal code?